# How to identify which dynamic ports are in use by tabs on Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I need to see which **dynamic ports** are in use by the opened tabs on **Chrome** or **Firefox**. Is there a built-in user interface for that? Or which tools are able to monitor them?

Comment: What are `dynamic ports` exactly? Something like `chrome://net-internals/#sockets`?

Comment: the ports that are used to connect different websites that starts from ~5000+. When the connection is lost, it is given back to pool. More info can be accessed from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29045432/282855 @wOxxOm

Comment: There's no such built-in functionality. As for the tools, try googling, I'm using `tcpview`.