# RemoteEndPoint vs. LocalEndPoint

Tags: c#, sockets, endpoints

As a beginner in C# networking, I wrote a simple Client-Server application. I'm connecting to my local IPAddress and port 8080 where the server is listening.

On Client Side:

```
        IPAddress remoteaddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        int port = 8880;
        TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient();
        tcpclient.Connect(remoteaddr, port);
        NetworkStream networkstream = tcpclient.GetStream();

        IPEndPoint RemAddr = (IPEndPoint)tcpclient.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
        IPEndPoint LocAddr = (IPEndPoint)tcpclient.Client.LocalEndPoint;

        if (RemAddr != null)
        {
            // Using the RemoteEndPoint property.
            Console.WriteLine("I am connected to " + RemAddr.Address + "on port number " + RemAddr.Port);
        }

        if (LocAddr != null)
        {
            // Using the LocalEndPoint property.
            Console.WriteLine("My local IpAddress is :" + LocAddr.Address + "I am connected on port number " + LocAddr.Port);
        }
```

the output is:

```
I am connected to 127.0.0.1 on port number 8880
My local IpAddress is :127.0.0.1 I am connected on port number 46715
```

So What's the difference between RemoteEndPoint and LocalEndPoint? What is the use of LocalEndPoint Port (46715 in my example) and where does it came from?
Thanks.

Comment: A TCP socket is a two sided connection - the local endpoint is your client's side, the remote endpoint is the server's side - that the server happens to be on the same hardware as the client doesn't mean you don't still have a pipe with two ends. The local port number is decided by the TCP stack at the time the connection is made.

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190176/how-does-port-number-really-work-in-tcp) may help you, your question is less specific to the .Net `TcpClient` class and more generally about how TCP/IP works.

Answer (score 2):

Remote End point will show you which client(ip) is connected to you're local end point (that is more likely to be the server ip 127.0.0.1)