# Is there a way to set the source port for a node js https request?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to set the source port for a node js https request?  I am not asking about the destination, rather the source, ie the port used to send the request.

The context is I am trying to send https requests from a specific port, rather than random ports, thus allowing for locking down iptables.  Node is not running as root, thus the port is not 443.

Update :
It appears there is a bug in Node. The options localAddress and localPort do not work, at least with a TLS socket.

Update : 
Found a similar question from last year. The answers were "don't do that", which seems dumb given that node is suppose to be a generic tool. [Nodejs TCP connection client port assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584395/nodejs-tcp-connection-client-port-assignment/36603462#36603462)

Comment: you want to change the system default port , or just want to change the port for your application ?

Comment: Add `:80` to the end of the link the client is accessing. (replace the 80 with whatever port you want)

Comment: I want to set the source port for a specific https request.  My https server is listening on 8443, since it isn't root.  In some cases my server needs to make https requests to a remote server. In those cases I want the requests to be sent from local port 8444.  How do I make that happen? I do not see a parameter for the source port.  There is a "default" but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: This is a total guess: perhaps try setting the localAddress property of the https.request object to include a port.  https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback

Comment: Was trying that as you were typing.  So far no luck.  The param localAddress is not well documented, so not sure how to use it.

Comment: Indeed, it doesnt work.  I get `throw new TypeError('localAddress must be a valid IP: ' + localAddress);` for `192.168.0.6:8444`, but it works fine for `192.168.0.6` without the port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like Node does not support binding a client port.  Apparently this isn't a feature that is used much, but it is possible.  This link explains port binding fairly well. https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-now-supports-websockets/  Not sure how to get the nodejs people to consider this change.

Answer (score 3):

The feature appears to be undocumented, but you can achieve this by setting BOTH the `localAddress` and `localPort` parameters for the options argument in https.request.

For more information, see the code here:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b85a50b6da5bbd7e9c8902a13dfbe1a142fd786a/lib/net.js#L916

A basic example follows:

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  hostname: 'example.com',
  port: 8443,
  localAddress : '192.168.0.1',
  localPort: 8444
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});

req.end();
```

Comment: I can't get localPort to work.  Tried with and without an agent.  Still see random ports in the iptables log.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `localPort` option in http.Request options to configure a source port. Seems like it's available since v14.x LTS. I tested out with Node v18.12.0 and it works. :)

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback

```
options.localPort <number> Local port to connect from.
```