# How the HTTP response reach the correct user agent

Tags: http, response, user-agent

I have a very beginner's question on HTTP response. I've seen the HTTP request packet contents and found that it has the User Agent specified in it. But that is not in HTTP response. How the system will identify the correct user agent. (BRIEF: How the HTTP response from Mozilla Firefox reaches Mozilla back but not going to Google Chrome, How the application identifies the response is for it)

Comment: You're looking at the too high a level - the communication is sent to the relevant *socket*, rather than specifying application by name.

Comment: So socket will get created for each application whenever it needs an HTTP communication?. If so where in the response the socket identification information is specified?. I am sorry if am asking simple questions. I am a tyro.

Comment: @RowlandShaw The socket is again a software piece, right? Where in the response it is specified that the data is for a particular socket?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can an application use port 80/HTTP without conflicting with browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957757/how-can-an-application-use-port-80-http-without-conflicting-with-browsers)

Comment: @RowlandShaw i've given the same link in my answer. I've read all the answers in the page and still did not have the answer for the question that i asked. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys,
I've got the answer for this question from stack overflow itself. Thank you @Rowland Shaw for giving me the guidance.
[Check answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957757/how-can-an-application-use-port-80-http-without-conflicting-with-browsers)