# Receiving http response inside a Docker container

Tags: http, docker, port, httpresponse, http-request

I am running a process, process A,  inside a Docker container that sends an HTTP reqeust to a process, process B, running natively on the host. Process B receives the request and after processing sends a response which process A does not receive. I believe this could be because I am not exposing the port on which the reply is sent. My understanding is that, this source port is randomly chosen and I am not sure how I can expose this port. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: This is not because of having or not having a port exposed. There may be multiple issues. For start try if you can ping any public IP from a container and share your docker run command. This will help troubleshoot.
Also I expect that if you send HTTP request to process A from outside docker it works properly...

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is that, this source port is randomly chosen and I am not sure how I can expose this port

It is only if your container runs with the `-P` option.
If you run with [`-p hostp_port:container_port` option](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) (with container_port being a port [`EXPOSE`'d](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) in the `Dockerfile` of the image from which the container is running), that will work.

Comment: I am not talking about Docker mapping a static internal port to a non-conflicting host port. I am talking about HTTP request opening a source port for communication to an HTTP server (One reference for this I can find is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957757/how-can-an-application-use-port-80-http-without-conflicting-with-browsers)

Comment: @Phelodas so that depends on the exact nature of the service opening that port then. I wouldn't know anything about it.